# How do I use animation in shiny in R to change data on plot without redrawing plot itself?

Tags: r, animation, optimization, shiny

I am researching and comparing various versions of particle swarm optimization and differential evolution, and to aid me in visualizing convergence of each variant, I have developed a simple shiny app.   My shiny app plots a contour map of the G2 function (code below), and then using simple animation it adds each generations' population as points on the contour plot, so I can see the evolution through generations.  I notice a lag in the animation that to be in the shiny app redrawing the contour plot each time, instead of simply "removing" current data points and adding new data points to the plot as it loops through the generations.  If I go below interval = 400 in animationOptions() of animate parameter, it does not render any faster, as that seems to be the fastest it can redraw the contour plot and data points.  Is there a way to have the contour plot drawn only once, then data points added and removed as it loops through generations?

```
G2 = function(x) {
     if (x[1] >= 0 & x[1] <= 10 & x[2] >= 0 & x[2] <= 10 &
         x[1] * x[2] >= 0.75 & x[1] + x[2] <= 15) {
         s <- cos(x[1]) ^ 4 + cos(x[2]) ^ 4
         p <- 2 * cos(x[1]) ^ 2 * cos(x[2]) ^ 2
         r <- sqrt(x[1] ^ 2 + 2 * x[2] ^ 2)
         f <- -abs((s - p) / r)
     } else {
         f <- 0
     }
     return(f)
     }





plotG2 <- function(main = "", sub = "") {
        S <- matrix(0, 101, 101)
        x1 <- (1:101 - 1) / 10
        x2 <- x1
        for (i in 1:101) {
            for (j in 1:101) {
                f <- -G2(c(x1[i], x2[j]))
                #f <- -rosenbrock(1, 100, c(x1[i], x2[j]))
                S[i, j] <- f
            }
        }

        col = terrain.colors(100)
        crange <- max(S) - min(S)
        image(x1, x2, S, col = terrain.colors(100), axes = T,
        xlab = "", ylab = "")
        contour(x1, x2, S, col = col[100], lty = "solid", add = TRUE,
        levels = c(0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4), vfont = c("sans serif",
        "plain"), drawlabels = F)
        title(main = main, sub = sub)
    }



 #Create list of random data points to cycle through
 popList = list()
     for (i in 1:5) {
          popList[[i]] = matrix(runif(80, 0, 10), nrow = 2, ncol = 40)
          }


library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
            plotG2(paste("G2 iter ", input$obs, sep = ""), "Particle Swarm Optimization")
            points(t(popList[[input$obs]]), col = "blue", pch = 19)

    })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
        sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel( 
                sliderInput("obs", "Number of observations:", min = 1,
                            max = 5, value = 1, step = 1, 
                            animate = animationOptions(interval = 400, loop = TRUE))
         ),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("distPlot"))
  )
)


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't.

Very long answer: Plots are rendered as png (see `?plotPNG`) before they're inserted in the web interface. So if you change something on the plot, you can't but rerender the entire image to be shown.